# ParametricGeometry using Vector3

Tags: javascript, three.js

Updating a script to a newer three.js and running into a problem with ParametricGeometry.  I keep getting error: "THREE.ParametricGeometry: Function must now modify a Vector3 as third parameter."  Below is what I have:

```
var restDistance = 20;
var xSegs = 15;
var ySegs = 10;

var clothFunction = plane(restDistance * xSegs, restDistance * ySegs, zSegs);
var cloth = new Cloth(xSegs, ySegs);

clothGeometry = new THREE.ParametricGeometry( clothFunction, cloth.w, cloth.h, true );
```

I assume the Function referred to in the error is the clothFunction.  I've tried this but same error - what am I not understanding?

```
var clothFunction = function (u, v) {
                return new THREE.Vector3(restDistance * xSegs, restDistance * ySegs, 1);
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was already asked here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/parametricgeometry-problem-with-parametric-function/3169

To make it short: Your parametric functions needs now a third parameter (`target`) that represents the results of your calculation. This approach avoids unwanted object creation by `new THREE.Vector3()`.

Comment: I don't understand This sets up my function:

`var clothFunction = plane(restDistance * xSegs, restDistance * ySegs);`

And this is the function (same as the plane function in the script you point to on discourse.threejs.org:

`function plane(width, height) {

 return function(u, v, target) {
  var x = u * width; //(u-0.5)
  var y = v * height;
  var z = 0;
  
  target.set( x, y, z );
 };
}`

which I've modified with target but when I call it like so it's not returning vector 3's anymore.

`var target = new THREE.Vector3();
this.position = clothFunction(x, y, target);`

Comment: ah I seem to need to use both `target.set( x, y, z );` and `return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);` - not very clear what target.set() is actually doing if I still need to create the vector3.

Comment: It's not necessary to create a new instance of `Vector3`. `ParametricGeometry` will reuse a single object for its calculations.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? - if I remove `return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);` it does not work.

Comment: I've meant it should be sufficient if you just set the values of the `target` vector. There should be no need for a return statement.

Comment: Ok well as I said if I remove the return it stops working.  Your answer was more or less the solution with some tweaking, which I suspect was to do with the way the script I'm working on was coded (this is the original that I'm updating: http://webgl.onikenkon.com/flag/), so I've accepted the answer.